# Get values of checkbox using Ajax with a $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

A small question where I think I'm very close to the goal.

I am trying to retrieve the value of all checkboxes coming from an array that are checked in order to send these values to my controller.
(This allows the user to select or not certain options).

I'm almost there, I just can not get the desired value in my int table.

I would like to put int in this int array the value '@ stuff.SubEvent_Zkp' but currently .val () puts 0 as a value in all the checkboxes sent to my controller (and also in the ajax call).

I still specify that # stuff.SubEvent_Zkp has a unique value.

I tried with data [0] and also with attr () but that does not seem to work.

**Table with checkboxes**

```
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var stuff in Model._Registration_SubEvents)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-3">@stuff.SubEvent_Name</td>
                            <td class="col-md-1">@stuff.SubEvent_Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                            <td>@stuff.SubEvent_Fee</td>
                            <td>@stuff.SubEvent_Note</td>
                            <td><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" name="CheckSub" id="CheckSub" value="@stuff.SubEvent_Zkp" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
```

**Code to put the values of @stuff.SubEvent_Zkp in favorite array**

```
    $.each($("input[name='CheckSub']:checked"), function () {
        favorite.push($(this).val());
    });
```

**And i put favorite in data (in the ajax call)**

```
data: { Id: id, Status: status,Checkin: checkin, Checkout: checkout, Cost: cost, Terms: check1, Info: check2, values: favorite },
```

Comment: So what are the actual values you see in the rendered html? Really not clear what specific problem is here

Comment: Well the table contains multiples objects of _Registration_SubEvents. In this model i have an int SubEvent_Zkp (who is unique) and this is the value i want to pass in my controller.
So what i did is a foreach to loop each checkbox who are checked and i need the values of SubEvent_Zkp.
Actually i receive [0] as values for each checkbox who are checked.

Comment: Try .is("checked") or .prop("checked") instead of .val(). It should return true. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @Shim-Sao I dont want to retrieve the value true/false, what i need is the value of 'stuff.SubEvent_Zkp' for each checkbox who are checked

Comment: What is the result of console.log($(this)) !? If it's the right object, you can try just .value

Comment: Did you look at the rendered html and see what is actually in each value attribute? Can inspect in browser dev tools elements inspector. Your `each` looks fine

Comment: I just notice that when i debug with Chrome, in each checkbox input i have id="0" value="0". So i guess i need to find a way to put the good value in value=""

Comment: Okey im totally crazy here! Actually my code was good, its just my call to the DB who was not taking the value of SubEvent_Zkp ... This is why i had always values of 0... Thanks for your answers, i really think charlietfl that you drived me in the good way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple use case I put together using data attributes that successfully retrieves all data attribute values from checkboxes and pushes them to an array (I'm using data attributes here because they seem to more aptly represent what you're trying to use the `value` attribute for):

```
         <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-3">name</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">date</td>
                <td>fee</td>
                <td>note</td>
                <td><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" name="CheckSub" data-checksub="1"  /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-3">name</td>
                <td class="col-md-1">date</td>
                <td>fee</td>
                <td>note</td>
                <td><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" name="CheckSub" data-checksub="2" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

script:

```
var array = [];
$.each($("input[name='CheckSub']"), function () {
    array.push($(this).data("checksub"));
});
//array now contains values 1 and 2
```

so your table row would look like:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-3">@stuff.SubEvent_Name</td>
    <td class="col-md-1">@stuff.SubEvent_Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
    <td>@stuff.SubEvent_Fee</td>
    <td>@stuff.SubEvent_Note</td>
    <td><input style=" height:17px; width:17px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:22px" type="checkbox" name="CheckSub" data-checksub="@stuff.SubEvent_Zkp"/></td>
</tr>
```

Additionally, ensure that the rendered values on your page are not all 0!

Comment: Thanks for your help it works! Actually i think my code was also working but i forgot to bring back the value of @stuf.SubEvent_Zkp from my DB.. This is why i had 0 values

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique. Try following:

```
... id="@stuff.SubEvent_Zkp" value="@stuff.SubEvent_Zkp"...
```

Comment: This won't account for OP's issue though and would actually be better to use common class instead